# What is the exact value of sin 2a

Tags: trigonometry

The question says a right angled triangle has sides and angles shown in the diagram. What is the exact value of $\sin(2a)$?

Thanks diagram shows a right angled triangle with a hypotenuse of $\sqrt{34}$, an adjacent of $5$, an opposite side from the angle of $3$, and an angle of $a$.

I'm new to this so help will be appreciated

[image]

Comment: Sorry, that should be sqrt (34), I'll edit it

Comment: **HINT**: Use the identity:$$\sin(2a)=2\sin(a)\cos(a)$$

Comment: I have added my own diagram to the question.

Answer (score 4):

We can find $\sin(2a)$ by using the double angle identity $$\sin(2a) = 2\sin(a)\cos(a).$$
We see that $\sin(a)$ is just $3/\sqrt{34}$. The cosine of angle a is $\cos a=5/\sqrt{34}$. So $$\sin(2a) = 2 \times \frac{3}{\sqrt{34}}\times \frac{5}{\sqrt{34}} = \frac{15}{17}.$$